# What subset of JSONAPI Ember data supports?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

So far I have been using custom JSON api and it have been so painful that I have decided to rewrite the backend to deal with JSONAPI instead of my custom JSON. However, reading the jsonapi.org specs it seems there are a lot of things to implement but I read somewhere I don't remember that ember-data actually uses a subset of the specifications.

However I cannot find anywhere in documentation, guides and googling as to which specs actually ember data uses. I want only to implement that given my time constraint. I will appreciate if anyone help me on this

Comment: To my knowledge, ember-data implement jsonapi and not just a subset of it. What framework do you use for your backend ? You can checkout this page http://jsonapi.org/implementations/ to find great tools to deal with JSON API format.

Comment: I'm developing on custom framework. Can you qualify your claim with any evidence? I'll try to find where I read that ember data doesn't implement every feature of jsonapi

Comment: My comment was just based on my experience with Ember and json-api, this is why I wrote it as a comment and not as a full answer. I'd be interested to read that article if you find it.

Comment: Sure,  thanks.  Am on mobile right now.  I'll try to find it tomorrow. Thanks for your time

Comment: so you are correct. I have looked at the announcement and there is no shred of subset. You can put that answer so I'll accept it. The link am referring to is this: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_json-api-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the discussion in comments, it appears Ember.js implements JSON API 1.0 and not just a subset of it.
Here is the announcement make back when Ember 1.13 was released : http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_json-api-support

For anyone looking for implementing a JSON API compatible backend, and therefore compatible out of the box with ember-data, there is a list of implementations for a large variety of languages/frameworks here : http://jsonapi.org/implementations/